# build application sucess message changed after published

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have one web application and developed some API.whenever API success i passed one message.I want changed after published this application changed message.So i want some idea to how to developed like this.

Comment: Please read first [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to put a flag into web.config files, for example add this key:

```
<appSettings><add key="IsDebug" value="True" /></appSettings>
```

and add this key into Web.Release.config file:

```
<appSettings><add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="IsDebug" value="False" /></appSettings>
```

Then you can check "IsDebug" key in your code, for example:

```
  NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string isDebug = appSettings["IsDebug"]);
if(isDebug == "True")
{
// your debug version message
}
then
{
// your release version message
}
```